# Update value of Map of Map

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap

I am using Java8 and I have one map

**`Map<Intege,Map<String,String>> mainMap=new HashMap()`**

currently i am updating value of inner map as below

```
Map map = mainMap.get(1);
map.put("abc", "abc+xyz");
mainMap.put(1, map);
```

Could anyone help me with Java8 or any other approach.

Comment: There's no need for that last line. This is sufficient: `mainMap.get(1).put("abc", "abc+xyz");` (assuming that the `1` key is guaranteed to have a value).

Comment: you need not to put back map **mainMap.put(1, map);** as it's already there, you are only working on a reference of same

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen yes, its working fine. Thanks

Comment: If map doesn't contains key in that case i need to create new entry in `mainMap`.

Answer (score 3):

First, you *must* avoid using raw types.

You have to initialize your main map properly using the diamond operator.

```
Map<Integer,Map<String,String>> mainMap=new HashMap<>()
```

That `<>` is very important.

Also, do not define `map` as just `Map`. It has to be defined as

```
Map<String,String> map = mainMap.get(1);
```

Now to the question itself. In similar situations, the issue is normally what happens when you haven't had a value for some key in the top map. You'd have to do something like this:

```
map = mainMap.get(1);
if ( map == null ) {
   map = new HashMap<>();
   mainMap.put(1, map);
}
map.put("some key", "some value");
```

If you didn't have the `if` clause, you'd run into a `NullPointerException` when you use `map.put(...)` if the main key didn't exist previously in the map.

Since Java 8, a few default methods were added to the `Map` interface, such that you can save up that boilerplate. The new idiom would be:

```
mainMap.computeIfAbsent(1, k->new HashMap<>()).put("some key", "some value");
```

If the map for `1` existed, it will be returned from `computeIfAbsent`. If it didn't exist, it will be created and placed in `mainMap`, and also returned. So you can use `put` directly on the result returned from `computeIfAbsent(...)`.

Of course, this has to be done with properly defined and initialized map types - again, don't use raw types.

Comment: i am not able to apply `**put**` directly on the result returned from computeIfAbsent(...).

Comment: @SagarGangwal Make sure that you initialize the main map properly. That is, `Map<Intege,Map<String,String>> mainMap=new HashMap<>()` - that `<>` is very important.